# Logo and favicon not uploaded from backend after upgrade PHP version 7.1 and Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2

I have upgraded the PHP version 7.1 and Magento 2.2.1. When I uploaded the logo and favicon from backend I get the error message "Invalid scope or scope id
"
[image]

Comment: Are you able to save other information from same section?

Comment: Yes ...I have faced problem when I uploaded the logo or favicons. Other things working fine.